# use $this->authorizeResource in boot() laravel backpack crud package

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

I need to use policy for crud controller in laravel backpack crud package.

I use :

```
    $this->authorizeResource(Post::class);
```

and i get this error :

> Method
>   App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PostCrudController::authorizeResource does
>   not exist.

How should i use Policy (specially resource policy) in laravel backpack crud?

Comment: in wich function is the line you posted?

Comment: in PostCrudController, it made with "php artisan backpack:crud post" commant

Comment: laravel version?

Comment: laravel 5.8 & backpack crud package 3.6

Comment: please post the function code in which you call  $this->authorizeResource(Post::class);

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that using Laravel's `AuthorizesRequests` trait. Generated Backpack CRUD Controllers don't have it by default, since not everybody uses this Laravel feature.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\MonsterRequest as StoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\MonsterRequest as UpdateRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class MonsterCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests;

    public function setup()
    {
    // ...
```